# Is it possible to display my iPhone on my computer monitor?

Tags: iphone, external-display

As the title says, is this possible?
I want to "mirror" my actions on the iPhone so it shows on the computer monitor.

We've seen this on the Apple key notes, but I am not sure if this feature is public.

Answer (score 6):

Many screencasts displaying an iPhone application simply use the iPhone Simulator, which is one option.

You can also take screenshots on the phone by quickly pressing the menu and the power/sleep button at the same time. The image is then saved to your "Camera Roll" and easily transferable to the computer

The other way is only possible with a Jailbroken phone - [Veency](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/09/18/veency-vnc-server-for-iphone/) is a VNC server for the iPhone, which you can connect to with a regular VNC client.

Answer (score 4):

The latest SDKs (beginning with 2.2, I believe), include TV-Out functionality. With a special cable connected to the iPhone dock connector, a program can send RCA signals representing its current screen contents through the iPhone->RCA cable. If you have a TV Tuner for your computer (i.e. I have an EyeTV Hybrid) with RCA inputs, you can display the screen contents of your iPhone directly in the TV viewer.

Comment: You have to buy the actual Apple made cable, though, which was $50 bux the last time I checked. OS 3.0 and newer checks the hardware for a special chip. If it doesn't exist, it no worky. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone is jailbroken you can use [DemoGod](http://www.plutinosoft.com/blog/projects/demogod)

Answer (score 1):

use screensplitr on jailbrocken iphone/ipod touch it works

Answer (score 0):

Release notes [iOS 3.2 (External Display Support)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009337-SW1) and [iOS 4.0 (Inherited Improvements)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW1) mentions that it should be possible to connect external displays to iOS 4.0 devices.
But you still have to jailbreak if you would mirror your iPhone screen...
[Related SO Question with updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289147/how-to-display-my-iphone-on-a-projector)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help. Haven't tried it out yet, will post again once I tested it.

http://blog.appideas.net/using-iphone-video-output-to-demo-your-apps-o

Answer (score 0):

This is a tool that will help you, i installed it myself

Here is the [link](http://learninginhand.com/blog/2013/3/13/mirror-ipad-iphone-ipod-to-your-screen-for-free)

Answer (score -1):

Do not we have an app which can stream the digital movie from iOS devices like iPhone or iPad to be played on a high definition LED or Plasma TV?

I know of an app air video server which can be used to display content played on computer or laptop on iOS device. But is there any app that can do the reverse & play the digital content from iphone to LED tv .