# TV out an iphone application

Tags: iphone

Using the UIScreen API is it possible to display the same app screen on both ipod screen and external display. I have tried using UIScreen but application is displaying only on external display, not on ipod screen. Please guide me on right way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to mirror iPhone/iPad screen on a monitor without jailbreaking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289147/possible-to-mirror-iphone-ipad-screen-on-a-monitor-without-jailbreaking)

Answer (score 0):

See:
http://www.expertisemobile.com/2010/06/24/presenting-your-apps-on-the-big-screen-screen-mirroring-for-ios/