# Where to find the iOS development session videos from Brad Larson?

Tags: iphone

Someone told me that Brad Larson has published good iOS development videos on iTunes U. He said there are supposed to be two classes similar like those from Stanford.

The terribly bad search UI of iTunes seems to lock me out of those videos. I can't find them. Not even when I search for Madison or Brad Larson. I'm also logged in while searching...

Can anyone point me into the right direction? Maybe Brad Larson himself? ;-)

Comment: Sorry about them not being visible in the main iTunes search.  This is the first class that the school has put on iTunes U, so we're not yet approved as an institution to be listed in the main directory.  The class is publicly available, but you have to use the direct link Vladimir provides below to get at it.  Sorry about that.  We should be searchable in the main iTunes directory soon.

Comment: Thanks Brad, good to know. It's not your fault, it's Apple's! No need for beeing sorry. Thanks for the great videos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Link to iTunes video](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032) can be found in Brad Larson's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) which, in turn, can be found at the very top of [top iphone answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iphone/topusers) ;)

And, in my opinion, those videos are not good - they are **very good** :)

Comment: Cool. The guy who told me about it a while ago said that Brad has released two classes - one for beginner, one for advanced. I can only find one of them. Or is that the complete set? Wonder why they don't show up with the iTunes search.

Comment: @BugAlert - I only teach the advanced course at the Madison Area Technical College.  The introductory one is much more hands-on, and wouldn't work well as a video.  In any case, there are plenty of great getting-started resources, like Stanford's video series.

Comment: Man, Brad, in the Core Data Video alone you're saying more than the Apple guys are saying in the entire stanford course videos. Had to put ice on my head to cool my brain down. Lot's of input ;-)