# iPhone Development: VNC Server Framework to mirror iPhone screen to Mac (Keynote)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, vnc, ios-frameworks, keynote

I developed an iPhone app which I now have to present an audience. For that purpose, I'm creating a presentation with Apple Keynote to show some facts — and after that, I also would like to hold a "live presentation" of the developed iPhone app.

To do that, I need to mirror the iPhone screen (that is, the iPhone running my app) up to my Mac. Best would be, if I could show this "live mirror view" right in Keynote — just as Apple does it in their keynotes.

My idea is to implement a VNC server into my app which mirrors the app to my MacBook which than acts like a VNC client. And at best I would need to show the VNC client's stream in Keynote.

iPhone as VNC Server --> MacBook as VNC Client --> Keynote showing VNC Client's "image stream"

**Does anybody knows a good VNC Server framework, which I could implement into my app?**

(And if someone has an idea related to the Keynote thing, I would love to hear about that, too.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something similar, but you'd need an additional television or monitor.

http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123

Comment: That's nice, but unfortunately it doesn't mirror any animations...
Edit: It does, if you enable the use of UIGetScreenImage. Looks fine and seems to be the best solution so far. Thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to jailbreaking you could install Veency which is a VNC server for iOS. Or you could use ScreenSplitr and iDemo which is for jailbroken devices too.

But note, VNC (and possibly ScreenSplitr too) will be laggy. It won't be as smooth as when Apple does it at their keynotes.

Comment: I jailbreaked my iPhone to give Veency and Screensplitr (in combination with iDemo) a try — but they are really very laggy. Too laggy in my opinion. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate is to look at the possibilities here:

[Possible to mirror iPhone/iPad screen on a monitor without jailbreaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289147/possible-to-mirror-iphone-ipad-screen-on-a-monitor-without-jailbreaking)

I have used the google project (http://code.google.com/p/iphoneos-screen-mirroring/) and it worked well for a course demonstration, but nothing that went to the app store.